# couch db - URI address

Tags: database, json, view, terminal, uri

I have bd "List" with some products like:

```
{
   "_id": "car1",
   "_rev": "1-6e192e3f87447ec187052941cf365071",
   "price": "950",
   "shop": "Shop1"
}
```

I have created view "Shop" to check what products/cars i have at one of 3 shops:

```
  function(doc) {
  emit(doc.shop,{product:doc._id});
}
```

Reduce function

```
function (key, values) {return (values);}
```

Now I would like to receive same but with URI so i did something like this:

```
...\curl -X GET .../List/_design/Shop/_view/Shop?key="Shop1"
```

why it doesn't work?
questions like: `...\curl -X GET .../List/_all_docs` works well
views also so why i can't get result from the view?

Answer (score 2):

If your function above is exactly what you have written, it's invalid javascript so your view will immediately crash and return nothing. You need quotes around `product`.